Problems viewing reports in windows 64 bits (Gx9 + Java + PostgreSQL)
I have an application developed in Gx 9.0 with Java and PostgreSQL generator. It works correctly, but I have the problem that it is not showing me the reports on a PC with Windows 10 Pro (No problems on other PCs). I suspect it is because GxDib32.dll does not work under 64 bits. Is there a 64-bit version of GxDib? Or will it be something else?
I have run the system on different PCs always without problems except PCs with Win 64 bits.
I have searched without success for 64-bit versions of gxdib

please install 32 bit JDK for 32 bit dll
